# Pass on a click on a control below

Tags: c#, winforms

in a Windows Forms Application, I have a PictureBox around the Cursor (using the MouseMove-Event), but want to pass the Click Event on to the Controls below it. At the moment the PictureBox Click-Event fatches every Click. Therefore I think I have to make this one PictureBox some kind of invisible for the Click Event.

How do I have to change the PictureBox Click-Event in order to do so?

Thanks in advance!
Toby

Comment: Describe your scenario better, which is the container and which is the content.

Comment: There is a PictureBox with its center at the Mouse Position. Moving around with the Mouse Movement (MouseMove-Event). And on my Form are a couple of other PictureBoxes on which I can click. But the one PictureBox at my Cursor always gets the Click-Events instead of the ones on the form.

Comment: I don't see how i could possibly use the code given in the answer there to solve my problem

Comment: Why does that accepted answer not work for you?  Did you try it?

Comment: I literally have no idea how i could try that. Where would i put that function and how do i use it?

Comment: You are only looking at the code, not the answer: `create a control inherited from Label and simply add the following code`  Change Label to PictureBox and use that new control in place of the PictureBox you are currently using.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example of how to create that PictureBox?

Comment: @Toby, create a class that inherits from PictureBox.  There are lots of examples of how to create a class on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks Amy. But it doesn't work for me as I first have to be able to click on the PictureBox in order to make it follow the cursor...

Comment: You want a control that you can click on and not click on? That's quite a moving target you got there.  Maybe you should share your code in order for this question to get re-opened and for you to get some help on this topic.